# How to make the popup window scrollable

Tags: javascript

I am having the following code that works to open a window with some size. 
Now need to make it scrollable. How to do that? I tried browsing but, couldn't find the right one.

```
window.open("xxx","","width=1200","height=60");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add scrollbars:

```
window.open("xxx","","width=1200, height=60, scrollbars=1");
```

Comment: didn't work. Even the height, width didn't work with this. Anything else to try?

Comment: Using IE 11 browser. This works fine. Just need to make it scrollable.   window.open("FindEmp.do?actionParameter=executeGetEmployees&employeeId="+empId,"","width=1200","height=60");

Comment: Have a look here for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: `window.open()` takes the maximum of 3 parameters, you cannot have more than 3 parameters otherwise it's incorrect syntax. So it's `window.open(URL)` or `window.open('URL', 'window name', 'window features')`. Take one more look at @DarrenSweeney code and then try again.

Comment: Thanks you all for your help. This worked for me.  window.open("FindEmp.do?actionParameter=executeGetEmployees&employeeId="+empId,"","scrollbars=yes,width=1200,height=340");

Comment: Great! If this answer helped you find a solution then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.open("xxx","","width=1200","height=60",scrollbars=1);
```

In your page ("xxx") which is used in this popup add this css:

```
yourcontainer {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```